# dictionaries TypeError: unhashable type:set

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, typeerror

I am attempting to split a string and then take a keyword from that string and find it in a dictionary. I would then want to call out that part of the dictionary, but i run into this error -

```
TypeError: unhashable type:set
```

- on the last line:

```
solutions = {'display': 'take it to a specialist to get fixed','screen':'test'}
problems = ['display','screen','cracked','broken','clear']``
words = ()
query = input("What is the problem? ")
query_split = query.split()
words = query_split
keyword = set(words) & set(problems)
print(keyword)
print (solutions[keyword])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `keyword = set(words) & set(problems)`, keyword becomes a `set`. You probably want to set keyword to an element from that `set` using the `pop` function.

i.e.

`keyword = keyword.pop()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that any of the other answerers are trying to understand what you're doing.

Try this.  I'm not sure what you plan on for `problems`, but this will at least run and hopefully get you in the right direction:

```
solutions = {'display': 'take it to a specialist to get fixed','screen':'test'}
problems = ['display','screen','cracked','broken','clear']
query = raw_input("What is the problem? ")
for word in query.split():
    print(word)
    print(solutions.get(word))
```

Notice the change of `input` to `raw_input` and accessing the keys of the dictionary as `str` types rather than a `set`.

Comment: thanks - this works and might even be more efficient than other ways im just not sure if it works for me.